# Why my data could not be deleted on cascade - TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to delete the user's profile when user's is deleted from the db. However, it seems that it does not work in my case. I have tried `OnDelete: "CASCADE" & cascade: ["remove"]` as well but it still does not work as intended. It always appear that the user is deleted from the db but the profile still reamins.

Here are the entities.

```
@Entity()
@Unique(['email', 'username'])
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  passwordHash: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date;

// Bi-directional
  @OneToOne(() => Profile, (profile) => profile.user, { cascade: ['remove'] })
  @JoinColumn()
  profile: Profile;
}

@Entity()
export class Profile {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  displayName: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  bio: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  profilePic: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  githubProfile: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  location: string;

  @Column('simple-array', { default: [] })
  techStack: TechStack[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdDate: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.profile)
  user: User;
}
```

Here is my call for the deletion of the user. In the delete call, I have tried to use `await this.usersRepository.remove(existingUser.id)` it still doesn't work

```
  async remove(username: string, user: User) {
    const existingUser = await this.findById(user.id);
    if (!existingUser) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    if (existingUser.username === username) {
      const userProfile = await this.profileService.findOne(
        existingUser.username,
      );
      if (!userProfile) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
      }
       //expected the delete call to delete both the user and profile
      await this.usersRepository.delete({ username: existingUser.username });
      return { message: 'User deleted successfully' };
    }
    throw new InternalServerErrorException();
  }
```